# Trying to use contains in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to find the values in a string using Indexof in ampscript.

```
           set @edt= "0,00"       
         set @displaySaving='initial'
  if IndexOf(@entryDiscountsTotal,@edt) > 0 then
             set @displaySaving='none'
           endif
```

It is totally working but the issue is I just wanted to check "0,00" I dont want to check if the value is "100,00" or "60,00" etc
But the above code is considering all those values which includes 0,00.
Can anyone help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should not use `contains`, but do a simple comparison:

```ampscript
SET @edt= "0,00"       
SET @displaySaving='initial'
IF @entryDiscountsTotal == @edt THEN
SET @displaySaving='none'
ENDIF
```